# Directory.getfiles(): specific names of files c#

Tags: c#

I have been trying to:

- Read all the files from a specific folder;
- Choose only the ones that end with a specific pattern name + .csv

What to I have so far:

```
                string[] fileEntriesout = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(dir + "\\" + "output\\", "*.csv*", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

This is working well but it gets all the .CSVs files;

What I tried:

```
                string[] extensions = { "_fv", "_body", "_out" };
            string[] fileEntriesout = Directory.GetFiles(dir + "\\" + "output\\", "*.csv*", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories).Where(f => extensions.Contains(System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(f).ToLower())).ToArray();
            string[] fileEntriesout = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(dir + "\\" + "output\\", "*.*", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories).Where(f => nextensions.Contains(new FileInfo(f).Extension.ToLower())).ToArray();
            string[] fileEntriesout = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(dir + "\\" + "output\\", "*.*", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories).Where(f => nextensions.Contains(new FileInfo(f).Name.ToLower())).ToArray();
            string[] fileEntriesout = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(dir + "\\" + "output\\", "*.*", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories).Where(f => nextensions.Contains(new FileInfo(f).Extension.ToLower())).ToArray();
```

I tried different ideas that I found but none of them seem to work.

Summing up:

1. I need that string[] gets all the .CSVs files that contain (usually at the end of the file name) the names: "_fv" or "_body" or "_out".

Thank you.

Comment: When you're forming paths use `Path.Combine` method. You're assuming by default the path separator is the `\\` character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `LINQ` and `EnumerateFiles` instead of `GetFiles` + `Path.GetFilenameWithoutExtension`:

```
string[] extensions = { "_fv", "_body", "_out" };
string[] fileEntriesout = System.IO.Directory.EnumerateFiles(dir + "\\" + "output\\", "*.csv", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    .Where(file => extensions.Any(ex => Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file).EndsWith(ex)))
    .ToArray();
```

[`String.EndsWith`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131430(v=vs.110).aspx) has an overoad that takes a `StringComparison`, if you want to ignore the case(f.e. allow `_Body` too):

```
EndsWith(ex, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
```

Comment: It is working! 
The only change that I made was:

Path.GetFilenameWithoutExtension to Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension
(the upper case N)

Thank you!